# If in the code there is ImageTk I can not open the .py file with python application

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have tried to open this program with double click using python application but it doesn't work.
I test it and I think the problem is the use of ImageTk.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = Tk()
root.title('Images')
root.iconbitmap('G_image.ico')


my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('2021_1.png'))
my_label = Label(image=my_img)
my_label.pack()

button_quit = Button(root,text='Exit Program',command=root.destroy)
button_quit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What means "doesnt work ?"

Comment: Better run the script manually in a terminal and see whether there is error shown in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any errors?

But I guess it's because you have to "pack" your label in the root window:

```
my_label = Label(root, image=img)
my_label.pack()
```

and to double click on the python file, try this:

right click on the file->open with->choose default program->more options->select python.exe file and click on.

Comment: So if you are under Linux, you have to give the file the execution rights with chmod, put the python sheibang: #!/usr/bin/env python3 at the begining of the file then I guess it will works

Comment: Without passing parent will use the default root window.  So basically your answer is the same as OP code.